# Using Excel data to create Word Doc caption labels in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, activexobject

I am trying to link a Word document report to an Excel database with VBA. I inserted various ActiveX text box controls in my document. I am manually entering each one of these text boxes with unique code ("Code"). The other text box controls will automatically populate based on the associated data in the Excel database. The matching factor will be the "Code".

When I run the following code, I receive a

> Run Time Error 13 "Type Mismatch"

on Row 16 (`If cell.Value...`). I don't have a lot of experience in VBA but I have seen many examples showing that the Value command should be tied to a 'Range' object. Thank you for your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim b As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range

'Set variables
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Book.xlsx")
Set b = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")
Set c = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
Set r = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows
Set cell = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000")

For Each r In c
    If cell.Value = ThisDocument.TextBox1.Value Then
        ThisDocument.TextBox2.Value = b.Value
   End If
Next r

exWb.Close
Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: did you mean `If r =` ? And you are setting `r` as a range of rows, but then using it later as a variable in your `For...Each`... ??

Comment: It would help your question if you could describe in words what your code is designed to do.  It looks like you're looking up a value on the worksheet, but then you populate TextBox2 with the same value you're searching for.  Are you matching a value in Col C and then pulling values from other columns on the matched row?

Comment: @TimWilliams I want my code to find the relevant row of data in my worksheet based on a common variable. This common variable is in the Word Document and in Excel worksheet. The code would scan the rows of the Worksheet (' r ' ) and find the variable that matches the Word Document text box (TextBox1). Once a match is found, it would populate other text boxes with values from other columns in the matched row. ...... I think now I see that my code is using the same value, as you noticed. Either way, I can't even get the same value to populate my TextBox2 value.

Comment: @braX I am setting R as all of the rows in my Worksheet so that I can scan the rows in a specific column to find a matching value.

Comment: Are you looking for the match in a specific column on the excel worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams  I edited my code slightly to add variable 'b', which is another column. The code should populate my TextBox2 with the column B value in the same row.

Comment: I guess my point was that using `For Each r In c` means that your previous line that sets a value to r serves no purpose as it is over-ridden.

Comment: @TimWilliams Not sure if you could help with this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306637/matching-subset-of-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, m, rw As Excel.Range

    'Set variables
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Book.xlsx")
    Set rng = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000")

    'Here we're looking for a match in ColC...
    '  change 3 to any other column you want to match on
    m = objExcel.Match(ThisDocument.TextBox1.Value, rng.Columns(3), 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then

        'got a match - fetch the other values from that row
        Set rw = rng.Rows(m) '<< get the matching row as a Range
        ThisDocument.TextBox2.Value = rw.Cells(1).Value 'value from colA
        ThisDocument.TextBox3.Value = rw.Cells(2).Value 'value from colB

    Else
        'no match - clear the other textboxes?
        MsgBox "No match found!"
        ThisDocument.TextBox2.Value = ""
        ThisDocument.TextBox3.Value = ""
    End If

    exWb.Close False 'no changes saved
    Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a Run-time error '438'- Object doesn't support this property or method- at Line 13, m=exWb.Match...